# Generate MkDocs pages in the browser

Tags: mkdocs

Is it possible to generate the pages for MkDocs dynamically/on-the-fly in the browser using JavaScript? In this case, the build process incl. all the required tools would not be necessary any longer. Since the build process generates static pages, I assume that generally this is possible, but haven't found any related information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. McDocs is written in the Python Language, not Javasript. Page builds can only be run from the command line.